# Regression variable trick

Tags: regression, econometrics

I am working with a set of data with a single dependent variable $Y$ and many potential explanatory variables $c_1,\cdots, c_n$.  When I define another variable as $c_1*c_2/Y$, I find that it with a few other variables $c_3, c_4, c_5$ explains $Y$ very well.  However, my concern is that because it is defined in terms of $Y$, I am just using a math trick that will make this work.  Am I allowed to do this, or does this break some rules of regression?  And, if so, is there a way to change my model so that it does not rely on a variable defined in terms of the dependent variable?

Comment: And it is actually bad and breaking everything. The explanatory variables must be 'unrelated' with the dependent variable. An explanatory variable cannot hold the variable, because *you dont know it*! :).... If so, you could do $c_1=Y$ and have the perfect result.....

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct, you cannot do this.

Models are there to make predictions.  That may not always be what we use them for explicitly, but anything you learn from a model that doesn't predict its response well is dubious.  What you are advocating is predicting $Y$ using some pieces of information, one of which is $Y$ itself.  That's not really a prediction, that's just unwinding your formula to get at the information inside.

The best thing to ask yourself is *what if I didn't know $Y$, could I still make a prediction*?  If the answer is no, then you don't really have a predictive model.

It's like me saying "I can predict how many fingers you are holding up behind your back" and then placing a mirror so that I can cheat.  Sure, I'm getting the right answer, but am I really doing anything impressive?  Would you bet money on me doing it in public?

This type of thing is generally called *data leaking*, but it usually comes up in less obvious circumstances.

I'm not sure what you mean

> Is there a way to change my model so that it does not rely on a variable defined in terms of the dependent variable?

Of course, just don't use any predictors that have Y explicitly or implicitly build in.

Comment: The second part was wondering if the expression I had could be solved to get a new variable that doesn't depend on $Y$ but is still good at predicting.  Since I end up with $Y=a_1*c_1*c_2/Y +  a_3*c_3+a_4*c_4$, and that expression can be solved to get $Y$ in terms of just the coefficients and variables with the quadratic formula, I was wondering if that would still leave me with a good predictor.

Comment: The underlying problem is your notation hides the unavoidable fact of *discrepancies* between the two sides of the equation. You need to account for them explicitly, which is usually done by adding a random variable $\epsilon$ to the rhs. Thus your model *really* is $Y = a_1c_1c_2/Y+a_3c_3+a4_c4+\epsilon$.  After you solve for $Y$, the random part will be complicated and violate the assumptions made by whatever procedure you are using to estimate the coefficients (such as OLS): $$Y=\left(\pm\sqrt{\left(-a_3 c_3-a_4 c_4-\epsilon \right)^2+4 a_1 c_1 c_2}+a_3 c_3+a_4 c_4+\epsilon\right)/2.$$

Comment: That is a really excellent point, and I would not have thought of it.  Thanks @whuber